# Using Particles (the amazing feauture of Qt) through Qt Jambi

Tags: java, qt, particle-system, qt-jambi

The title states it all; I'm trying to use the Particles feature available in Qt through Qt Jambi Libraries. I know that to use Particles in Qt you have to import it first using something like:

```
import QtQuick.Particles 2.0.
```

But whenever I try to import QtQuick using Qt Jambi Libraries it shows that there is no such a class with that name. Is Particles class included in Qt Jambi but under another class, or is it not even a feature supported by Qt Jambi yet?

Comment: Code? We need code to help you. _EDIT_: import statements cannot have spaces in the package path.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That looks like QML code call, not Java code call. That line would be used in QML in order to use Particles objects there.

We have QML support in theory, in a way that the system should support it, but no-one has so far been interested on testing it and providing a guide how to use it, so I’d rather declare it doesn’t work until someone interested steps in to do it :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, looking forward to it to be implemented as soon as possible